# python3 interpreter for emacs instead of 2.7

Tags: emacs, python-3.x, python-2.7, fedora

I'm new to Fedora 17 and Emacs, can't figure out how to tell my emacs to use the newest version of python.

I found some info that I should change python-python-command variable or show path to new interpreter, how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python 3 in emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071701/python-3-in-emacs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(setq py-python-command "/usr/bin/python3.1")
```

should be added to your .emacs file

Comment: vi .emacs in home directory in insert mode I had put this line at the end of file. "Esc" (quit from insert mod) and :x to save changes. And all works thank you.

Comment: @ГеннадийРябкин, to expand on what HaloWebMaster said, if an answer helps you, you should upvote it; and if it solves your problem, click the outline of the checkmark next to it ("accept" the answer). [The FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) has some more detail.